# how to keep CSS in separate files?

Tags: css, gatsby

By default Gatsby drumps all the css required on a given html document into its header making css caching impossible:

```js
import "./foo.css"
import "./bar.css"
```

results in:

```html
<style data-href="/styles.f6ce41623bc6fbf912c0.css">
  .foo{color:green}.bar{color:orange}
</style>
```

`/styles.f6ce41623bc6fbf912c0.css` contains exactly that stylesheet.

is there a way to keep `foo.css` and `bar.css` in separate files without loosing the ability to minify and autoprefix everything?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality is called **bundling**, and Gatsby uses Webpack to do it. You could [alter the Webpack configuration](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-custom-webpack-config/), but I’d say there is really no point in doing that.

Bundling and code-splitting resources is a crucial part of why Gatsby is so fast. By bundling the CSS for every page makes sure that only resources required by the current page are loaded. Gatsby also [caches all of the resources](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-gatsby-is-so-blazing-fast-c99a6f2d405e/#code-split-and-cache) it has loaded, so you don’t need to worry so much about resource economy.

I found a code snippet from [a Gatsby issue comment](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/1526#issuecomment-433347822), which replaces inline `<style>` elements with `<link>`s, but I wouldn’t recommend doing that without going through some performance measurement.

Comment: _"By bundling the CSS for every page makes sure that only resources required by the current page are loaded"_



well it could also do that by only adding `<link href="foo.css" />` on all the pages that need it. I don't see the point in loading every stylesheet in every page while half of the stylesheets could already be in the browser cache at this point

Comment: it might make sense on a single page with http < 2 but not a large-scale page in a modern environment

Comment: If you use `<Link>`s and `navigate()` to move between pages, as you should, Gatsby downloads only parts it's missing. The pre-generated HTML that you’re talking about is used only for the first page the user requests.